# Scale div from particular point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one Div and one small round image on html page. When I run html page div is scale 0 so didn't display. When I click on small image that div scale to 1 in middle of the window. My div position is absolute. My problem is when I scale div to 1 it will scale from middle of the window. Now, I want to **scale from small image** so looks like that **window open from that small image**. Small image is movable(draggable).

**My code**

```
$('.divclass').css('transform','scale(1)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `jquery-ui`s `draggable()` in order to drag the image around.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').on('click',function(){
        $('.holder').toggleClass('scale');
    });
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

that javascript if for the image when click the red box will appear on the middle, click click again it will be gone.

a sample fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xABB/).
And btw, i think this is what your question's says, or I might be mistaken, coz its kinda confusing question.

Comment: no that's not my question. i can able to drag image. i need just scale from particular point. like from left 100px and top 200px;

Comment: when you click the image in my fiddle it also scales but in the center. You want the scale to be where?

Comment: i want to scale from left 100px and top 200px to middle

Comment: then change the `top` and left in the `css` bro. you can adjust it wherever you want to.

Comment: yes but i need that value dynamically. Like, suppose i change drag image from left:100px to 200px and top:200px to 400px then div scale from left:100px and top:400px to middle.

Comment: oh, lemme see what I can think off